# svn unignore rvmrc

Tags: svn, rvm, svnignore, rvmrc

I am trying to commit .rvmrc to svn

```
svn list
>> Gemfile
>> Gemfile.lock
>> config.rb
>> config.ru
>> source/
svn status
svn propedit svn:ignore . (delete ".rvmrc")
svn status
>> M      .
>> ?      .rvmrc
echo "#" >> .rvmrc
svn status
>> M      .
>> ?      .rvmrc
svn commit -m "rvmrc"
svn list
>> Gemfile
>> Gemfile.lock
>> config.rb
>> config.ru
>> source/
```

As a result there are no rvmrc on the server. I dont understand this magic. How to commit rvmrc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you `svn add .rvmrc` before committing?

Comment: thanks for fast reply. My IDE usually do auto-add and I forgot this =)